# Linearization of exponential function with expectation

Tags: probability, analysis

I ran into the following formula in my class:
$$
E[\exp(X)]\approx \text{constant}+E[X].
$$
Since the linearization takes place at $X=0$, I don't understand why the constant in the formula is not directly written as $1$. Thanks for any hint!

Comment: You are right. What is the power series expansion of $\exp(X)$?